# hook change state doesn't update context provider's value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I have 2 component, and a context provider, when I call my hook at parent level, I have no issue changing the state and having those 2 component getting the value via context

working demo of contex api usage but I call change state at parent level which is not what I wanted
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-51e2ky?file=index.js

I want to change state at inner component with hook, but I don't see the value been changed when I click on the `navbar login`.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rgenmi?file=Navbar.js

parent:

```
const App = () => {
  const {user} = loginHook()
    return (
      <UserContext.Provider value={user}>
        <Navbar />
        <Content />
      </UserContext.Provider>
    );

}
```

Navbar.js

```
const Navbar = () => {
  const user = React.useContext(userContex)
  const {setUser} = loginHook()

  return <div>{user ? <span>{user.name}</span> : <button onClick={() => {
    setUser({
      name: 'jane'
    })
  }}>navbar Login</button>}</div>
}
```

custom hook

```
const loginHook = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = React.useState(null)

  return {
    user,
    setUser
  }
}
```

I can pass setUser from parent to children but I want to avoid that, I expect I can use context api and react hook seamlessly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, you're only setting the `user` value in the context, which is why getting the correct value will work.

However, in your `Navbar.js` component, you are making a call to `loginHook`, which will create a new "instance" of that hook, effectively having its own state.

I suggest you add the update function in your context as well, as such

```
const App = () => {
  const {user, setUser} = loginHook()
    return (
      <UserContext.Provider value={{ user, setUser}}>
        <Navbar />
        <Content />
      </UserContext.Provider>
    );

}
```

That way you can access the `setUser` in your children as well, e.g.

```
const Navbar = () => {
  const {user, setUser} = React.useContext(userContex)

  return <div>{user ? <span>{user.name}</span> : <button onClick={() => {
    setUser({
      name: 'jane'
    })
  }}>navbar Login</button>}</div>
}
```

Also, small note: it's best to start you custom hook with `use`, as that's a best-practice when writing your own hooks.

Important caveat however, this is not really a good practice. If your `user` were to change, all components that are only listening to `setUser` will also get an update an thus do a useless rerender. You can solve this by using two different contexts, one for the value, and one for the updater. You can read more about this [here](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/how-to-use-react-context-effectively)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the parent's context information from the child, no. You'll need to pass something to the child from the parent that the child can use to let the parent know that the context needs to be updated (such as the parent's copy of `setUser`). You can do that via a prop or by adding `setUser` to the context, though I'd lean toward just doing it as a prop to components that need to be able to set the user, rather than context they all have access to.

The reason using `loginHook` in both places didn't work is that each component (`App` and `Navbar`) has its own copy of `user`. This is fundamental to how hooks work. (If it somehow made them share the state information, `useState` wouldn't work at all — all state would be shared across all components.) Dan Abramov's [A Complete Guide to `useEffect`](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/) may be a helpful read (it's more about how hooks and components work than it is specifically about `useEffect`).

Answer (score 0):

You must note that custom hooks do not share instance references, so if you use the loginHook in App and another one in Navbar, they will create 2 separate states and updaters

Now using a setter from custom hook will now update the state in context.

You can restructure this by writing your loginHook so that it internally uses context and then using it

```
const App = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState();
    return (
      <UserContext.Provider value={{user, setUser}}>
        <Navbar />
        <Content />
      </UserContext.Provider>
    );

}

const Navbar = () => {
  const {user, setUser} = loginHook();

  return <div>{user ? <span>{user.name}</span> : <button onClick={() => {
    setUser({
      name: 'jane'
    })
  }}>navbar Login</button>}</div>
}
const loginHook = () => {
  const {user, setUser} = React.useContext(UserContext)

  return {
    user,
    setUser
  }
}
```

Now there are multiple ways to write this code, However the best way in the above scenario is not use a custom hook at all since it anyway is not useful

```
const App = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState();
    return (
      <UserContext.Provider value={{user, setUser}}>
        <Navbar />
        <Content />
      </UserContext.Provider>
    );

}

const Navbar = () => {
  const {user, setUser} = React.useContext(UserContext);

  return <div>{user ? <span>{user.name}</span> : <button onClick={() => {
    setUser({
      name: 'jane'
    })
  }}>navbar Login</button>}</div>
}
```

Comment: so hook is no needed when I use context? then when to use hook? is context api to replace hook? now I'm confused when to use hook and context since both work as manage states between multiple components.

Comment: You can take out things into a custom hook when you have a common functionality that is being used at multiple places. For instance a simple fetch request being hit from different pages. Also custom hooks do not manage a common state between components but context does. Think of context as a data store aPI like redux, a minimum version of it

Comment: `Also custom hooks do not manage a common state between components`, is this statement true? sounds wrong..

Comment: @AndreThonas, yes this is true, if  you have a state within a custom hook, each of the instances that use it will have its own state reference and will not refer to the same one

Answer (score -1):

In your `Navbar.js` you use your `loginHook` hook which will create a new separate state that is different from the state used in your `App.js`. You need to write your hook so that is uses the context instead of `useState`:

```
/* UserContext.js */

const UserContext = createContext();

export const UserProvider = ({children}) => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

    return (
        <UserContext.Provider value={{user, setUser}}>
            {children}
        </UserContext.Provider>
    );
}

export const useLogin = () => useContext(UserContext);
```

Then use it like that:

```
/* App.js */

import {UserProvider} from './UserContext';

const App = () => (
    <UserProvider>
        <Navbar />
        <Content />
    </UserProvider>
);
```

and

```
/* Navbar.js */

import {useLogin} from './UserContext';

const Navbar = () => {
  const {user, setUser} = useLogin();

  return <div>{user ? <span>{user.name}</span> : <button onClick={() => {
    setUser({
      name: 'jane'
    })
  }}>navbar Login</button>}</div>
}
```

Comment: so hook is no needed when I use context?

Comment: @AndreThonas Well it hides the internals from the one using the hook, which is generally a better design. In that case it hides the actual `UserContext` from the user. Technically in this simple case you could directly do `useContext(UserContext)` but my proposed solution is cleaner.

Comment: your solution is nice but it's not flexible. Imagine I have another component one day want to add one setState which isn't related to User, then I have to duplicated another set of context.js

Comment: @AndreThonas Well you did not specify that this is a requirement. Also you shouldn't put to much unrelated state into the same context as that may lead to many unnecessary re-renders in your app. If you need a general purpose global state manager you are better off using `redux`. Maybe I don't understand what you mean. How is my solution unflexible? Could you elaborate?